# Changing class with Javascipt

Tags: javascript, class, toggle

Forgive me for my silly question, I'm a beginner :/
For some reason, I can't use Jquery due to some stuff with Divi theme on Wordpress.

I need to change CSS class to some links so that they will change color if selected
(these links reveals different divs contents)

I've tried this:

```
function linkcolor() {
   document.getElementById(arguments[0]).className='serveminus'; 
   for(var i=1; i< arguments.length-1; i++) {
      document.getElementById(arguments[i]).className='serve'; 
   }  
}
```

When I call the function I'll add the anchors' ids as parameters.
The first one will be shown as "selected" (serveminus) one while the other will be grayed out (serve).
Somehow I've got this working but I need to have this other feature:
When a link is already selected and it has the "serveminus" class, if clicked again, the class changes back to "serve".

If I add the following condition I guess it generates a nonsense loop....

```
 if (document.getElementById(arguments[0]).className='serveminus') {
    document.getElementById(idlink).className='serve';
 } else {
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to set an onClick event listener:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener

Pseudo code might be:

```
if link is clicked and link is selected
  set event listener on link 
    onClick change class to 'serve'
    remove event listener
```

Comment: So if I add this line inside the funciton I should see an alert?

`document.getElementById('link1').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
alert('I have heard a click');});`

Comment: @bipo Yes! That will work for testing. In production make sure to declare a function (not an anonymous function) and remove the event listener when it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an eventListener that will toggle the class, I would first have all the links that you want to apply this style to in an variable. And apply the code block below .

```
var linkArray = doucument.querySelectorAll('navigationLinks');
// Example-> var linkArray = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a');

for(var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
  linkArray[i].addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('classToToggle');
  })
}
```